# How to Achieve Master-Master Replication in MongoDB for Two Databases in Different Locations?

Tags: database, mongodb, replication, database-replication, master-master

I'm working on a project where I need to deploy two MongoDB databases in different geographical locations. I want both databases to work independently, allowing reads and writes on both sides. However, I also need a mechanism to ensure that changes made in one database are synced to the other in a master-master-like fashion.

What strategies or technologies can I employ to achieve this master-master replication setup in MongoDB? Are there any best practices or specific considerations for handling synchronization across different locations? I'd appreciate any insights, examples, or recommended tools to implement a robust and reliable solution for keeping two MongoDB databases in sync.

I've explored Active-passive, but it doesn't entirely fulfill my requirement for a master-master setup with databases deployed in different geographical locations. While primary-secondary replication is excellent for high availability and fault tolerance, it doesn't support simultaneous writes to both databases, making it fall short for my specific use case.

Comment: "allowing reads and writes on both sides" - simple answer: not possible with MongoDB. Only solution would be a sharded cluster where you put `mongos` in each geographical location. However, for the data bearing nodes you can have **only one** PRIMARY and only the PRIMARY permits write operations. Or you can deploy synchronization by yourself on application level.

Comment: perhaps cassandra may cover this use case: https://bikas-katwal.medium.com/mongodb-vs-cassandra-vs-rdbms-where-do-they-stand-in-the-cap-theorem-1bae779a7a15

Comment: No, mongodb does not provide master-master replication.

Look at Couchbase, it is document oriented model as mongodb, but with master-master replication.